# How to include cells with today date in SUMIFS formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got raw data in a sheet with columns containing items number, product type, date, etc...

Date format is: 25-01-18 9:20

I'm trying to get a SUMIFS formula to report number of items arrived today.

Like =SUMIFS(Sheet2!G1:G924,Criteria1,Criteria2,etc)

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what column has the date/time?

Comment: Sheet2, column H

Answer (score 1):

If there are times in the data you can do >= today and < today+1 to count all items on todays date, e.g. if your date/times are in column `H` this sums column `G` for all today's items

`=SUMIFS(Sheet2!G:G,Sheet2!H:H,">="&TODAY(),Sheet2!H:H,"<"&TODAY()+1)`

Or for a simple count of today's items

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!H:H,">="&TODAY(),Sheet2!H:H,"<"&TODAY()+1)`

Comment: Thanks, let's try with the first one, I need to add more criteria from other columns like J and K (type and product)

Comment: Not working, I set this one:

=SUMIFS('Quote Received'!G:G,'Quote Received'!H:H,"">=" & INT(Today(),'Quote Received'!H:H,"<" & INT(Today()+1",'Quote Received'!J1:J924,"Carrier VoIP",'Quote Received'!K1:K924,"=",'Quote Received'!C1:C924,"<>MODCOM")

Comment: Quote Received is Sheet2

Comment: You don't need INT and you have some quotes wrong, also all ranges need to be the same size - try this: =SUMIFS('Quote Received'!G:G,'Quote Received'!H:H,">="&Today(),'Quote Received'!H:H,"<"&Today()+1,'Quote Received'!J:J,"Carrier VoIP",'Quote Received'!K:K,"=",'Quote Received'!C:C,"<>MODCOM")

Comment: ...also what is "=" supposed to do?

Comment: "=" --> blank cells

Comment: No, wait, my fault